# EntityFramework (6) and async ( waitingForActivation)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.5, async-await, entity-framework-6

I've downloaded [**EF6**](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.0.0-alpha2) ( in order to use `async`)

So I wrote this simple method :

```
  public async Task<List<int>> MyasyncMethod()
      {
          var locations = await MyDumpEntities.AgeGroups.Select(f=>f.endYear).ToListAsync();
          return locations;
       }

   ...Later...


  DumpEntities1 MyDumpEntities = new DumpEntities1();
  var data = MyDumpEntities.AgeGroups.ToListAsync();
  MyasyncMethod().ContinueWith(s => { Response.Write("f"); });
  MyDumpEntities.Dispose();
```

But I don't see anything on the screen and when I inspect `data` I see this :

[image]

*p.s. this is the  `ToListAsync` signature*
[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: You're not `await`ing this call, you should probably go for `var data = await MyDumpEntities.AgeGroups.ToListAsync();`...

Comment: Isn't he awaiting the call in the call to MyasyncMethod() which returns the Task?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek noope  http://i.stack.imgur.com/WqdZb.png

Comment: @RoyiNamir Your method (`Page_Load`) is not marked as `async`, so no wonders there :) Either you have to mark method as `async` and `await` the call or wait for the execution somehow (continuation, blocking wait)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing it of off the comments and the line that you have problem with:

```
var data = MyDumpEntities.AgeGroups.ToListAsync();
```

What will `data` type be? `Task<List<AgeGroup>>`. That's right, not `List<AgeGroup>`.
So, you either have to mark the `Page_Load` as async (if possible):

```
public async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var MyDumpEntities = new DumpEntities1())
    {
       var data = await MyDumpEntities.AgeGroups.ToListAsync();
    }     
}
```

Or wait for the execution somehow (continuation, blocking wait).

Another thing (someone else might want to correct that if I'm wrong), but since you're using continuation for the second call, I would be very careful of disposing the context outside of continuation. It might turn out that you dispose the context preemptively. In this particular case, you're not using the context in the continuation, but it looks suspicious...

So I'd either

```
MyasyncMethod().ContinueWith(s => { Response.Write("f"); MyDumpEntities.Dispose();});
```

Or just use `async` there too

```
var result = await MyasyncMethod();
Response.Write("f");
MyDumpEntities.Dispose();
```

and add `Async="True"` to the page directive

Comment: I thought that if `MyasyncMethod` is already marked as async , I dont need to do it also in the `page_load`........bummer

Comment: @RoyiNamir Well, if you want to use `await` inside a method, that particular method has to be marked as `async`. Of course, it's a good idea to go 'async all the way down', even in helper methods...

Comment: `async all the way down` - well said. didn't know i should do that.

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out that the correct solution is to use `await`, but I don't see a good explanation of *why*.

There are two reasons why the original code is wrong. First, you're using `ContinueWith` without capturing the context in an ASP.NET application, so the continuation (the `Response.Write` call) does not have a request context and therefore has no response to write to.

`await` takes care of this for you by capturing the context before the `await` and using that to resume the rest of the method; in this case, it will capture an `AspNetSynchronizationContext` representing the current request/response.

The other reason is that asynchronous code will run concurrently. So, `MyasyncMethod` will begin executing, reach its `await`, and return an uncompleted task to `Page_Load`. `Page_Load` then attaches a continuation to that task and *continues executing*, disposing the context. So the context may be disposed while the `ToListAsync` request is still running.

`await` also fixes this for you because it will "pause" the `Page_Load` method until `MyasyncMethod` is complete.

As a final note, you should also consider these points when using `async` in ASP.NET:

1. You must target .NET 4.5. Do not use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`.
2. You must set `targetFramework` to 4.5, *or* set `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to true.
3. (WebForms only) Set `Page.Async` to true.
4. Consider using `RegisterAsyncTask` instead of `await`. I usually prefer `await` because different methods have more separation of concerns, but the ASP.NET team prefers `RegisterAsyncTask` because there is a single "synchronize" point after `PreRender` where the runtime waits for all the operations to complete. [See this article for how to use `RegisterAsyncTask`.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)
5. Build in your own request timeouts. Asynchronous ASP.NET requests do not automatically use the normal timeouts that are built-in to synchronous ASP.NET requests. There are two options:

   - Use the `HttpRequest.TimedOut` cancellation token.
   - (WebForms/`RegisterAsyncTask` only) You can add an asynchronous timeout by setting `Page.AsyncTimeout` and having your `async` method take a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: I think the article has a missing async. http://i.stack.imgur.com/P3mnN.png ( exactly my situation here)

Answer (score 1):

`ToListAsync` returns a `Task`. Mark `Page_Load` as async, then you can use await in it.

Rough rule: If something returns a Task (contains "Async" in method name), you have to await it.

Also, when using async/await you don't have to use `ContinueWith`. Just await your own method and place the `Write` call in the next line.

```
DumpEntities1 MyDumpEntities = new DumpEntities1();
var data = await MyDumpEntities.AgeGroups.ToListAsync();
var dataFromMyMethod = await MyasyncMethod()
Response.Write("f");
MyDumpEntities.Dispose();
```

and add `Async="True"` to the page directive