# Will opening a DbContext per ToListAsync end up blocking a connection pool?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

Related : [EntityFramework (6) and async ( waitingForActivation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587157/entityframework-6-and-async-waitingforactivation)

However, it does not address awaiting multiple items, just one. My goal was to accomplish something along these lines

```
var car = db.Cars.ToListAsync(); 
var people = db.People.ToListAsync(); 
Task.WhenAll(car,people);
```

Unfortunately I got this runtime exception (I should have known really)

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Database contexts aren't thread safe. Okay. So now I am considering factoring out the calls to be methods and then awaiting both method calls (or an easy way to demo this would be to just wrap each of the db calls shown above in `using(db){}` statements). Regardless, the problem is that with that pattern it will require a new DbContext for each `ToListAsync`.

Will using a DbContext per ToListAsync call be a threat to a connection pool? Is this an anti pattern?

Comment: It will not be a threat to the threadpool, as it is not using the threadpool, it is using IO completions ports. You will of course have more connections to the database, and your database might not handle this faster if it is busy already as it is.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten - **connection** pool. The number of current connections to a database. I didn't mention the thread pool here :)

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. You will of course have more connections, one per DbContect effectively. They will all be pooled for later reuse though.

Comment: Mostly I am curious if this is an anti pattern or if it is a commonly used practice. Has anyone experienced negative affects from using contexts in this fashion?

Comment: This is a common approach in server scenarios (ASP.NET), where each ASP.NET request will open an independent `DbContext`. It's not as common with desktop apps but there's no reason it wouldn't work. As @KrisVandermotten pointed out, this will increase the load on your DB server. Note that a single SQL Server machine will not scale nearly as well as a single ASP.NET server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will using a DbContext per ToListAsync call be a threat to a connection pool?

It will use one connection per `DbContext`.  Depending on your scenario, this may oversubscribe, or it may not.  It depends a lot on the expected usage and the capabilities of your database.

> Is this an anti pattern?

Not necessarily.  This puts more strain on the DB, as it's going to perform both queries simultaneously.  The upside is you're *potentially* increasing the throughput on the client side (in this case, ASP.NET being the client to the DB), which may outweigh the extra strain.  Measuring is really the only way to know whether the benefits outweigh the strain on the DB.